# Output console in wxpython can't print cyrillic

Tags: python, encoding, wxpython

Even tho I have `#coding=utf-8` at the top of my .py document and covnvert cyrillica strings to utf-8 before passing them to the console, it still gives me:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table) UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position
>   16: character maps to

What else can I do?

This is my `to_utf8` function:

```
def to_utf8(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return dict([(to_utf8(key), to_utf8(value)) for key, value in obj.iteritems()])
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [to_utf8(element) for element in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, unicode):
        return obj.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return obj
```

Comment: You need to mention what version of wxPython and which Python along with which OS. It would also be great if you could post a small, runnable example.

Comment: This should not be a wxPython problem: What your program is telling you that it has got a unicode string and gets an error trying to change the encoding to `cp1252`. So you should tell us your OS AND the offending line, which throws the error. If the line is something like `print somechars`, try `print [somechars]`.

Comment: I'm using 64-bit Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: @nepix32 but I can `print` it just fine, it only fails when I try to write it in the wx area with `WriteTExt` method of `wx.TextCtrl`. In both cases I tried with and without converting to utf8.

Comment: Print the bad str to the console (`print [badstr]`, with the [, ]-brackets) and post it here. BTW: print also (from the console: `import wx; wx.__version__`).

Comment: Here it is: `\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa2\xd0\x90\xd0\x9b\xd0\x98\xd0\x9d\xd0\x93\xd0\xa0\xd0\x90\xd0\x94`
The actual string is "СТАЛИНГРАД" in cyrillic

Comment: Ok, now you can answer your question yourself: Is your String Unicode/UTF-8 or something else? Which encodings does wxPython accept?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to tell the encoding by looking at this, I think wxPython accepts utf-8. But I'm alredy using the `to_utf8` function to no avail.

Ok it's utf-8 for sure, I checked without using the to_utf8 function and it's:

`\u0421\u0422\u0410\u041b\u0418\u041d\u0413\u0420\u0410\u0414` which is definately unicode, so now the question is why is wxPythong making this error internally?

Comment: You still owe us `wx.__version__`. But most interestingly, I fail at the last character `Д`.

Comment: `wx.__version__` is `3.0.0.0` . My knowledge of encoding is very small, so I'm not sure what to make of this( the fact that it fails at the last character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going the wrong way: Obviously *the bytes in* your `str`  *are* `utf8`. However, python does not care what is in a `str` (a sequence of UTF-8-encoded unicode codepoints is just another sequence of bytes from pythons viewpoint).

**This remains to be answered:** For reasons I don't know it tries to decode to `cp1252`.

If you spoon-feed `utf8` to python, it works. Equally, if you explicitly prefix the `u` literal, Python does know what is in the character sequence *(it is a `unicode` type now)*. `str != unicode != utf8`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
# works
mystr= "СТАЛИНГРАД".decode('utf8')
# this also works
mystr= u"СТАЛИНГРАД"
# uncomment to make code fail
#mystr= "СТАЛИНГРАД"
app = wx.App(0)
frm = wx.Frame(None, -1, mystr)
frm.Show()
app.MainLoop())
```

wxPython 3.0 is unicode only and accepts utf-8 AND unicode.

Comment: wait, so when I have a utf8-encoded string I have to decode it to unicode before passing to wxPython?

Comment: You should post a minimal .py-file showing the problematic behaviour **as attachment** (so that we can examine the hex-values). Maybe your file was saved as `cyrillic` and not as UTF-8. Prepending `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`to the .py file is only a hint for python. It does not guarantee that your editor chooses the proper encoding for you (e. g. Notepad++ will always start with ANSI instead of UTF-8, which can be annoying).

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have a unicode build of wxPython. The latest version is only in unicode, but I know in wxPython 2.8 (and possibly 2.9), you could get ascii versions. If you already know you have a unicode build, then you'll probably want to take a quick look at the wxPython wiki:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Internationalization
- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/internationalization.html
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/RecipesI18n

This tutorial is also quite useful:

- http://zetcode.com/wxpython/in18/

Hopefully one of these resources will help you figure out your issue.